# GridBagLayout in Java wont work

Tags: java, jpanel, gridbaglayout, gridx

Ive been trying to make adjust my display the way i want it, but it doesnt seem to work. I want to use GridBagLayout to make something like this:

[I want to sort panels like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjuIm.png)[image]

Ive found a piece of code, and edited it:

```
public class GBLPanel extends JPanel 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    public GBLPanel(Dimension appdim)
    {
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(gbcComponent(0,0,2,1,0,0), gbc);               
        add(gbcComponent(0,1,1,1,0,50), gbc);            
        add(gbcComponent(1,1,1,1,0,50), gbc); 

    }

     private JPanel gbcComponent(int x, int y, int w, int h, int ipadyx, int ipadyy){

        gbc.gridx = x; 
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.gridwidth = w;
        gbc.gridheight = h;

        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;

        gbc.ipadx=ipadyx;
        gbc.ipady=ipadyy;

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField text = new JTextField("(" + w + ", " + h + ")");
        panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("(" + x + ", " + y + ")"));        
        panel.add(text);
        return panel;

    }

}
```

[but it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw2G4.png)
[image]

and i cant figure out how to shape it as i want, anyone can help ? Thanks very much !

Answer (score 2):

A `BorderLayout` would probably be easier to do this for you.

But if you want/need to use a `GridBagLayout`, the current problem you are having is that you are setting the `weight` for both x and y for each panel to 1. Meaning they will all be distributed evenly.

Try changing them to reflect the values you want by doing something like this

```
public GBLPanel(Dimension appdim)
{
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    // Pass in weights also
    add(gbcComponent(0,0,2,1,0,0, 1, 0.25), gbc);  // 100% x and 25% y
    add(gbcComponent(0,1,1,1,0,50, 0.25, 0.75), gbc); // 25% x and 75% y
    add(gbcComponent(1,1,1,1,0,50, 0.75, 0.75), gbc); // 75% x and 75% y

}

private JPanel gbcComponent(int x, int y, int w, int h, int ipadyx, int ipadyy, double wx, double wy)
{
    gbc.gridx = x;
    gbc.gridy = y;
    gbc.gridwidth = w;
    gbc.gridheight = h;

    gbc.weightx = wx;  // Set to passed in values here
    gbc.weighty = wy;

    gbc.ipadx=ipadyx;
    gbc.ipady=ipadyy;

    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextField text = new JTextField("(" + w + ", " + h + ")");
    panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("(" + x + ", " + y + ")"));
    panel.add(text);
    return panel;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Java Devil, you helped me alot. I actually used BorderLayout to make the first picture, but I've started learning Java recently, and I didn't know how to make resize handler. and I've also read somewhere that GridBagLayout is the most flexible, so i wanted to try it.